# How to integrate $Ae^{-\frac{y^2}{B}}\cdot \cos^2\left(\frac{2\pi }{L}y\right)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, exponential-function

I have the following function,

$$\psi (y)=Ae^{-\frac{y^2}{B}}\cdot \cos^2\left(\frac{2\pi }{L}y\right)$$

and need to find the indefinite integral:

$$\int \:\psi\left(y\right)\:dy$$

I can integrate each term seperately, for example with the first term:

$$
\begin{split}
\int \:Ae^{-\frac{y^2}{B}}\:dy&= A\:\int \:e^{-\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{B}}\right)^2}\:dy\\
&=A\sqrt{B}\:\int \:e^{-u^2}\:du\\
&=A\sqrt{B}\:\cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\operatorname{erf}\left(u\right)+C\\
&=A\sqrt{B}\:\cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{B}}\right)+C\\
\end{split}
$$

However, I can't seem to figure out how to integrate the whole function. I would be grateful if anyone could lend me a hand with this.

Comment: Do you know Fourier transform?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Could you step me though the maths, or is it too complex?

Comment: My idea was to use the formula $$ \cos^2(x) = \frac{1+\cos{(2x)}}{2}$$ and then the Fourier transform of the gaussian function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What would the formula for the Fourier transform be and how would it be applied in this case?

Comment: It is not worth to learn an entire theory just to solve this instegral, furthermore the Fourier transform act well on definite integral. It looks like the result is comples, is it possibile?

Comment: I don't know if integration yields non-complex values, though I didn't intend it to. I created the function so that it yields $dy/dt$ so I am integrating with respect to $y$.

Comment: If the integration does only yield complex values I'd still like to know what they are and how to find them.

Comment: Have you considered writing the cosine in exponential form?

Comment: @Allawonder How would that work and how does it help with the integration?

Comment: @TomAllen Euler's formula told us that $e^{\operatorname{i}x}=\cos x+\operatorname{i}\sin x$, therefore $\cos{x} = \frac{e^{\operatorname{i}x}+e^{-\operatorname{i}x}}{2\operatorname{i}}$

Comment: Yes, I can see how that could be useful. I'll see what I can do with that.

Comment: Still don't know how to integrate the new function: $$\int Ae^{-\frac{y^2}{B}}\left(\frac{e^{i\left(\frac{2\pi \:}{L}y\right)}+e^{-i\left(\frac{2\pi \:\:}{L}y\right)}}{2i}\right)^2$$Have I done something wrong with substitutions? I don't often deal with integrating complex numbers.

Comment: Also, I have another question worth mentioning; how does the integral of a function, which only yields real numbers, possibly yield complex numbers?

Comment: @TomAllen That's *not* the cosine. It is given by $$\frac12(e^{iy}+e^{-iy}).$$

Comment: Sorry, I guess I jumped the gun while setting the equation up. Thanks @Allawonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First step:**
reduce the power of cosine.

Since
$$\cos^2 x=\frac{1+\cos{(2x)}}{2}$$
the integral becomes
$$
\begin{split}
I &= \int A e^{-\frac{y^2}{B}}\left(\frac{1+\cos{\left(\frac{4\pi y}{L}\right)}}{2} \right) \operatorname{d}y\\
 &=\frac{A}{2} \left[\int  e^{-\frac{y^2}{B}} \operatorname{d}y+ \int e^{-\frac{y^2}{ B}} \cos{\left(\frac{4\pi y}{L}\right)} \operatorname{d}y \right] \\
&=\frac{A}{2} \left[\frac{\sqrt{B\pi}}{2} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt B}\right)+ \int e^{-\frac{y^2}{B}} \cos{\left(\frac{4\pi y}{L}\right)} \operatorname{d}y \right]\\
\end{split}
$$

**Second step:**
transform the cosine into the exponential form

Let
$$
J_{\alpha,\beta} =\int e^{-\alpha y^2} \cos{(\beta y)} \operatorname{d}y 
$$

For the Euler's formula we have
$$
\cos(\beta y) = \frac{e^{\operatorname{i}\beta y} + e^{-\operatorname{i}\beta y}}{2}
$$
where $\operatorname{i}$ is the imaginary unit ($\operatorname{i}^2=-1$). 
Therefore
$$
J_{\alpha,\beta}=\int e^{-\alpha y^2} \cos{(\beta y)} \operatorname{d}y =\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-\alpha y^2+i\beta y} \operatorname{d}y +\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-\alpha y^2-i\beta y} \operatorname{d}y 
$$

**Third step:** Solve generalized gaussian integral.
For the solution we requires to solve
$$
\int e^{-(ax^2+bx)} \operatorname d x 
$$
completing the square we get
$$
ax^2+bx = (\sqrt{a}x)^2+bx+\frac{b^2}{4a}- \frac{b^2}{4a} = \left(\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)^2 + \frac{b^2}{4a}
$$

So the integral became
$$
\begin{split}
\int e^{-\left(\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a}} \operatorname d x &= e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}} \int e^{-\left(\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)^2 } \operatorname d x \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt a} e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}} \int e^{-z^2} \operatorname d z \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt a}  \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2} e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}}\operatorname{erf}(z) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}}\operatorname{erf} \left(\sqrt a x + \frac{b}{2 \sqrt a} \right)
\end{split}
$$
when we used the substitution $z = \sqrt a x + \frac{b}{2 \sqrt a} $, $\operatorname dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt a} \operatorname d y$.

Now in our case  $\alpha = a$ and $b = \pm i \beta$ (hence $b^2 = -\beta^2$), so we get
$$
J_{\alpha,\beta}=\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}e^{\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}}\left[\operatorname{erf} \left(\sqrt \alpha x - \operatorname i\frac{\beta}{2 \sqrt \alpha} \right)+\operatorname{erf} \left(\sqrt \alpha x + \operatorname i\frac{\beta}{2 \sqrt \alpha} \right)\right]
$$
In our case $\alpha = \frac{1}{B}$  and $\beta = \frac{4 \pi }{L} $, so 
$$
\begin{split}
\int e^{-\frac{y^2}{B}} \cos{\left(\frac{4\pi y}{L}\right)} \operatorname{d}y &= \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{B\pi}e^{\frac{B\left(\frac{4 \pi }{L}\right)^2}{4}}\left[\operatorname{erf} \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{4 \pi }{L}}} - \operatorname i\frac{4 \pi \sqrt B}{2L} \right)+\operatorname{erf} \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{4 \pi }{L}}} + \operatorname i\frac{4 \pi \sqrt B}{2L} \right)\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{B\pi}e^{\frac{4B\pi}{L^2}}\left[\operatorname{erf} \left(\sqrt{\frac{L}{\pi}}\frac{x}{2} - \operatorname i\frac{2 \pi \sqrt B}{L}\right)+\operatorname{erf} \left(\sqrt{\frac{L}{\pi}}\frac{x}{2}  + \operatorname i\frac{2 \pi \sqrt B}{L} \right)\right] \\
\end{split}$$

Finally, the results is

$$
\boxed{I = \frac{A\sqrt{B\pi}}{8} \left\{  2\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt B}\right) + e^{\frac{4B\pi}{L^2}}\left[\operatorname{erf} \left(\sqrt{\frac{L}{\pi}}\frac{x}{2} - \operatorname i\frac{2 \pi \sqrt B}{L} \right)+\operatorname{erf} \left(\sqrt{\frac{L}{\pi}}\frac{x}{2}  + \operatorname i\frac{2 \pi \sqrt B}{L} \right)\right] \right\}\\+C}
$$

PS: I'm not sure about this, because Wolfram Alpha  [returns](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+A*exp%28-y%5E2%2FB%29*cos%5E2%284*pi*y%2FL%29) other solution.

Comment: Thank you for that solution, it's a great help. However, I am still wondering how I could test this function with real values (since that's what I originally intended it for, but it contains the imaginary unit). I am assuming I wouldn't be able to plot it on a cartesian plane?

Comment: Can you provide some context? What does this function represent?

Comment: I've realised that the function yielding complex numbers is fine. Thanks for the help!